# javascript closing div append

Tags: javascript

My div is closing itself.

```
<html><head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#wrapper").append( '<div id="content"><br>test');
        $("#wrapper").append('<br>whatever');
        $("#wrapper").append( 'sfga<br></div>' );
});
</script>

</head><body>

<div id="wrapper">
</div>

</body></html>
```

The div is automatically closing after `test` is output and not after sfga like it should.

How to fix this?

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to break things into separate steps like this?

Comment: There's more code with if functions and while loops.  I did this to simplify the problem and make things easier to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirty fix:

```
var sHTML = '<div ="content"><br>test<br>whateversfga<br></div>';
$("#wrapper").append(sHTML);
```

Proper way of doing it:

```
var oNewDiv = $('<div id="content">').append('<br />').append('test');
$("#wrapper").append(oNewDiv);
```

Why this happens? Because jQuery is automatically creating proper DOM elements when given raw HTML, while letting you append to them with the above chaining.

Comment: This does not seem to work.  I have put all my text into the stuff variable:    

var newdiv=$('<div id="content"').append(stuff);
$("#wrapper").append(newdiv);

and it is not working now...

Comment: You need to properly close the `<div` so that jQuery will identify it as valid element: `var newdiv = $('<div id="content">').append(stuff);` see also [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/6fCQk/)

Answer (score 1):

You are operating on a DOM, not a text stream.

Despite the abstraction that jQuery provides, you can deal only with elements, not with tags.

```
 var html = '<div ="content"><br>test' +
            '<br>whatever') + 
            'sfga<br></div>';
 $("#wrapper").append(html);
```

(note that `<div ="content">` is nonsense, but I have no idea what you meant by it so I haven't tried to fix it up).

Comment: if I want to add multiple lines to the text can I use html+='more words' ?

Comment: Most likely he just forgot `id="` in front. :)

Comment: Correct, added the id in now.

Comment: @David19801 — You can use any of the standard methods to manipulate a string.

Answer (score 1):

Why not combine those three `append` calls?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#wrapper").append( '<div ="content"><br>test<br>whateversfga<br></div>' );
});
```

If you need to put other things inside the div, you could create a new div and then append other elements to it, doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var $newElem = $('<div class="content"></div>');
    $newElem.append($('<p>test<br />test</p>'));
    $("#wrapper").append($newElem);
});
```